# Android: Progress dialog and toast

Tags: android, progressdialog, toast

Can anyone help me how to put a progress dialog that loads for 5 seconds and shows a fast after? Here's the code:

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                saveState(phoneNo, message);

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                Intent setIntent = new Intent(Edit_Message.this, Main.class);
                startActivity(setIntent); 
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to put a 5 second progress dialog and a tots that prompts that the message has been sent. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
showProgress ();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    }, 5000);
```

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
public  void showProgress () {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: How far you reached now? Are you getting progress dialog?

Comment: Yes, progress dialog is ok, but the 5 seconds delay of it doesn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5765/discussion-between-sandy-and-kev)

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to make progess bar for  5 second then Progress Dialog & Java thread is use [** Progress dialog**](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=proressdialog%20android%20example&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.androidpeople.com/android-progress-dialog-example&ei=ZLXlTuTgEI6rrAfck4SKCA&usg=AFQjCNEqIvczSF952g3dyhLWAMZVcCIGgA&sig2=y0xbD1spNzHKxKG0iliYWA&cad=rja)but if you need it to dynamic then [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is best practice to use.
as per your description you need to raise Toast after complete load then you can make it in after complete thread or in `asynctask` , `onPostExecute()` will use.